# Rspec not reaching controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, automated-tests

I'm writing controller specs, but for this particular controller, the test is behaving strangely. It seems to not be going into the controller at all.

The spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
require './app/controllers/entidades_controller'

describe EntidadesController do
  describe '#create' do
    context 'quando parametros validos' do
      it 'cria entidade' do
       expect {
          post :create, entidade: {cnpj: '84.215.775/0001-74'}
          }.to change {Entidade.count}.by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

The controller:

```
def create
  abort("?????????????????????????????????????????????????????????")
  @entidade = Entidade.new(entidade_params)
  @entidade.status = true
  respond_to do |format|
    if @entidade.save
      configuracao_inicial
      format.html { redirect_to @entidade, notice: 'Entidade criada com sucesso.' }
      format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @entidade }
    else
      puts "#{@entidade.errors.full_messages}"
      format.html { render :new }
      format.json { render json: @entidade.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

When running this spec, the execution should be interrupted and the question marks should be printed as soon as the `abort` line is reached, I've used this in other test cases before. However this is the output of the test:

```
F

Failures:

  1) EntidadesController#create quando parametros validos cria entidade
     Failure/Error:
       expect {
          post :create, entidade: {cnpj: '84.215.775/0001-74'}
          }.to change {Entidade.count}.by(1)

       expected result to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
     # ./spec/controllers/entidades_controller_spec.rb:10:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.13257 seconds (files took 3.78 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/entidades_controller_spec.rb:9 # EntidadesController#create quando parametros validos cria entidade
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Do you have any filter(s) that might be interrupting the flow before even reaching the controller action (ex. authentication)?

Comment: Do you have any authorization? Or before action? And do you really have to require controller in spec file?

Comment: Yes I do have authentication. I can't believe I forgot about it... Thanks so much both of you, that's probably it!